# MySQL database structure, users and dates

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 3 columns `USER, DATE, TEXT`, I want to insert updated TEXT into each column daily with a date for each USER. I have USER set as my primary key how about structuring something like this? Im new to mysql. my inital thought were something like this

```
USER1 DATE TEXT
      DATE TEXT
      DATE TEXT
USER2 DATE TEXT
      DATE TEXT
      DATE TEXT
```

But then I dont think this would work seeing how the USER is the primary key.

Comment: I would use a combination of user & date as your primary key

Comment: Thank you everyone, Reading everyones answers helped me to better understand :)

Answer (score 1):

The primary key should be `(user, date)`.

```
USER1 DATE1 TEXT
USER1 DATE2 TEXT
USER1 DATE3 TEXT
USER2 DATE1 TEXT
USER2 DATE2 TEXT
USER2 DATE3 TEXT
```

Answer (score 1):

I would make two tables in this database. One table will hold your user's account information. The second will hold the text you want to save using a unique id, the users id, the date, and the text.

Comment: If he wants to store detailed information about his users, i definitely think this is the best option.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you need two tables with `one to many relation`.

```
Table1: User
UserId, Name

Table2: Messages (or whatever)
MessageId, UserId, Date, Text
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be use 2 tables
one with only "user" as primary key
another with "user" "text" "date" where "user" is foreign key

main
user1
user2

second
user1 text1 date1
user1 text2 date2